# ValueError: bad file descriptor, width = os.get_terminal_size().columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-os

I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\myname\OneDrive\Desktop\DxubleG's follwo bot\bot.py", line 10, in <module>
    width = os.get_terminal_size().columns
ValueError: bad file descriptor
```

The part of code is:

```py
from colorama import init, Fore, Style
from discord.ext import commands
import subprocess
import requests
import discord
import ctypes
import os

init(convert=True)
width = os.get_terminal_size().columns
ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTitleW('dxuble.lol')
token = 'Nzc0ODIxNjc1OTQyMjgxMjQ4.X6dW6w.sDk8D4FRFJXy06tEJCRLMqy6pFc'
prefix = '.'

title = [
    r'',
    r'',
    r'',
    r'',
    r'',
    r'',
    r''
]

intents = discord.Intents().all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix, case_insensitive=True, intents=intents)
bot.remove_command('help')
```

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 2):

You're almost certainly having this problem for one of three reasons:

1. Without a terminal
2. With a "virtual terminal" provided by some IDE that doesn't connect `sys.stdout` to a true file descriptor, and fails to monkey-patch `os.get_terminal_size`
3. Possibly on a weird system when querying the terminal size for `stdout` doesn't work even when it is connected to a terminal

Either way, the solution is the same: Follow [the guidance from the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.get_terminal_size) ("`shutil.get_terminal_size()` is the high-level function which should normally be used, `os.get_terminal_size` is the low-level implementation."), and [use `shutil.get_terminal_size()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.get_terminal_size), which always provides a result, checking, in order:

1. The environment settings for `COLUMNS`/`LINES`
2. If they're not defined, it attempts to use `os.get_terminal_size()`
3. If that fails (either system doesn't support the query, or not connected to a terminal), it provides a fallback result, defaulting to `(80, 24)` (you can pass in your own `tuple` of default values instead if that's not a good default for you, e.g. `cols, lines = shutil.get_terminal_size((128, 32))` to fall back to a larger default dimension)

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this script in your terminal?
I tried to run your code that fails in my terminal and it worked as intended.
[image]

Comment: Oh, I was running with python idle

Comment: @NewYorker: Yeah, IDLE uses a virtual terminal that doesn't adhere to the normal rules. For interactive use, I'd stick to `ipython` (or plain Python REPL if you won't use `ipython` for whatever reason); `ipython` is still using a "real" terminal, so you don't have these problems.